# function that checks if number is in tree

Tags: haskell

Im trying to write a little program that can check whether a given number appears in a Tree. This is my code:

```
import Prelude

data Tree = Node Int [Tree]

Tree happytree = Node 5 [Node 1 [Node 6 []],Node 8 [],Node 2 [Node 1 [],Node 4 []]]

contains1 :: [Tree] -> Int -> Bool
contains1 [] x = False
contains1 (a:as) x = contains a x || contains1 as x

contains :: Tree -> Int -> Bool
contains (Node x []) y = x==y
contains (Node x as) y = x==y || contains1 as y
```

Im getting the error message

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘Tree’
Perhaps you meant ‘True’ (imported from Prelude)
```

What is this supposed to mean?
I was wondering if somebody could give me an advice how to write my contains function without writing the help function contains1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you write `Tree happytree`, do you mean `happytree :: Tree` and on a separate line `happytree = ...`?

Comment: Why are you using type constructor `Tree` on the LHS of the definition of `happytree`? Instead of `Tree happytree =  Node ...`, you probably mean `happytree :: Tree; happytree = Node ...`.

Comment: yes thank you! I was so sure that I always declared my variables this way^^ I edited the question.

Comment: _One_ question per post, and _do not significantly change_ your question. Otherwise answers will get out of sync (see the start of Sebastian's answer, and mine). By the way, if you have working code, and you want to know how to write it better or whether it's good/bad practice, head over to [codereview.se].

Comment: ok ill change it back and thanks for the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the error from the declaration `Tree happytree = ...`. It seems a C-style habit snuck into your code and you tried to declare the constant with a type in the wrong way.

It's just `happytree = ...` and the compiler deduces the type. If you want to specify it explicitly, you do it like with the functions and write `happytree :: Tree` on a separate line.

As for getting rid of `contains1`, it's testing whether **any** of the trees in the list contains the value, so you can get rid of it this way:

```
contains :: Tree -> Int -> Bool
contains (Node x []) y = x==y
contains (Node x as) y = x==y || any (`contains` y) as
```

I'm using section syntax here for the partially applied `contains`; you could instead write a lambda `\a -> contains a y`.

Comment: You can even make `contains` easier, since `any` returns `False` on an empty list.

Comment: Is this faster then the original algorithm? Because it seems to me that any is doing more or less the same as my contains1 function.

Comment: It's doing exactly the same thing as the `contains1` function, it just replaces the explicit recursion with the higher-order function `any`. Unless your tree has special properties such as keys being ordered, there's no way of making it faster than this brute-force approach.

Comment: @SebastianRedl I wouldn't call that brute force. It's just a linear search.

Answer (score 5):

While Sebastian's answer tells you the problem (type declarations belong in their own lines), note that the error message stems from the following:

```
data Id Int = Id Int

Id x = Id 5
```

This is perfectly valid, since you're binding with a pattern `Id x`. It's similar to

```
(x:_) = [5..]
```

However, in order to do this, you need a *data constructor*, e.g. something that can create a value, like `Node`, whereas `Tree` is a *type constructor*, it creates (or in this case *is*) types. That's why you end up with that rather cryptic error message:

> ```
> Not in scope: data constructor ‘Tree’
> Perhaps you meant ‘True’ (imported from Prelude)
> ```

Either way, you can fix this by removing `Tree` from `Tree happytree`.

---

For your other question, use `any`:

```
contains :: Tree -> Int -> Bool
contains (Node x as) y = x == y || any (`contains` y) as
```

Note that `elem`-like functions (on lists `elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`) usually take the predicate first and the container last, which makes the application of `contains` easier:

```
contains :: Int -> Tree -> Bool
contains y (Node x as) = x == y || any (contains y) as
```